# Correctly reading the types from file in PySpark

Tags: python, apache-spark, dataframe, pyspark

I have a tab-separated file containing lines as

```
id1 name1   ['a', 'b']  3.0 2.0 0.0 1.0
```

that is, an id, a name, a list with some strings, and a series of 4 float attributes.
I am reading this file as

```
rdd = sc.textFile('myfile.tsv') \
    .map(lambda row: row.split('\t'))
df = sqlc.createDataFrame(rdd, schema)
```

where I give the schema as

```
schema = StructType([
    StructField('id', StringType(), True),
    StructField('name', StringType(), True),
    StructField('list', ArrayType(StringType()), True),
    StructField('att1', FloatType(), True),
    StructField('att2', FloatType(), True),
    StructField('att3', FloatType(), True),
    StructField('att4', FloatType(), True)
])
```

Problem is, both the list and the attributes do not get properly read, judging from a `collect` on the DataFrame. In fact, I get `None` for all of them:

```
Row(id=u'id1', brand_name=u'name1', list=None, att1=None, att2=None, att3=None, att4=None)
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Absolutely sure all columns are tab delimited? (might seem like a stupid question but you never know). Do a hexdump if in doubt; a space has hex code 20, a tab is 09

Comment: @jDo Absolutely sure and checked

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is properly read, it just doesn't work as you expect. Schema argument declares what *are* the types to avoid expensive schema inference not how to cast the data. Providing input that matches declared schema is your responsibility.

This can be also handled either by data source (take a look at `spark-csv` and `inferSchema` option). It won't handle complex types like array though.

Since your schema is mostly flat and you know the types you can try something like this:

```
df = rdd.toDF([f.name for f in schema.fields])

exprs = [
    # You should excluding casting
    # on other complex types as well
    col(f.name).cast(f.dataType) if f.dataType.typeName() != "array" 
    else col(f.name)
    for f in schema.fields
]

df.select(*exprs)
```

and handle complex types separately using string processing functions or UDFs. Alternatively, since you read data in Python anyway, just enforce desired types before you create DF.