# Spark DataFrame not respecting schema and considering everything as String

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, apache-spark-mllib, scala-collections

I am facing a problem which I have failed to get over for ages now.

1. I am on Spark 1.4 and Scala 2.10. I cannot upgrade at this moment (big distributed infrastructure)
2. I have a file with few hundred columns, only 2 of which are string and rest all are Long. I want to convert this data into a Label/Features dataframe.
3. I have been able to get it into LibSVM format.
4. I just cannot get it into a Label/Features format.

The reason being

1. I am not being able to use the toDF() as shown here
   https://spark.apache.org/docs/1.5.1/ml-ensembles.html

   ```
   val data = MLUtils.loadLibSVMFile(sc, "data/mllib/sample_libsvm_data.txt").toDF()
   ```

   it it not supported in 1.4
2. So I first converted the txtFile into a DataFrame where I used something like this

   ```
   def getColumnDType(columnName:String):StructField = {

           if((columnName== "strcol1") || (columnName== "strcol2")) 
               return StructField(columnName, StringType, false)
           else
               return StructField(columnName, LongType, false)
       }
   def getDataFrameFromTxtFile(sc: SparkContext,staticfeatures_filepath: String,schemaConf: String) : DataFrame = {
           val sfRDD = sc.textFile(staticfeatures_filepath)//
           val sqlContext = new org.apache.spark.sql.SQLContext(sc)
            // reads a space delimited string from application.properties file
           val schemaString = readConf(Array(schemaConf)).get(schemaConf).getOrElse("")

           // Generate the schema based on the string of schema
           val schema =
             StructType(
               schemaString.split(" ").map(fieldName => getSFColumnDType(fieldName)))

           val data = sfRDD
           .map(line => line.split(","))
           .map(p => Row.fromSeq(p.toSeq))

           var df = sqlContext.createDataFrame(data, schema)

           //schemaString.split(" ").drop(4)
           //.map(s => df = convertColumn(df, s, "int"))

           return df
       }
   ```

When I do a `df.na.drop() df.printSchema()` with this returned dataframe I get perfect Schema Like this

```
root
 |-- rand_entry: long (nullable = false)
 |-- strcol1: string (nullable = false)
 |-- label: long (nullable = false)
 |-- strcol2: string (nullable = false)
 |-- f1: long (nullable = false)
 |-- f2: long (nullable = false)
 |-- f3: long (nullable = false)
and so on till around f300
```

But - the sad part is whatever I try to do (see below) with the df, I am always getting a ClassCastException (java.lang.String cannot be cast to java.lang.Long)

```
val featureColumns = Array("f1","f2",....."f300")
assertEquals(-99,df.select("f1").head().getLong(0))
assertEquals(-99,df.first().get(4))
val transformeddf = new VectorAssembler()
        .setInputCols(featureColumns)
        .setOutputCol("features")
        .transform(df)
```

So - the bad is - even though the schema says Long - the df is still internally considering everything as String.

**Edit**

Adding a simple example

Say I have a file like this

```
1,A,20,P,-99,1,0,0,8,1,1,1,1,131153
1,B,23,P,-99,0,1,0,7,1,1,0,1,65543
1,C,24,P,-99,0,1,0,9,1,1,1,1,262149
1,D,7,P,-99,0,0,0,8,1,1,1,1,458759
```

and

```
sf-schema=f0 strCol1 f1 strCol2 f2 f3 f4 f5 f6 f7 f8 f9 f10 f11
```

(column names really do not matter so you can disregard this details)

All I am trying to do is create a Label/Features kind of dataframe where my 3rd column becomes a label and the 5th to 11th columns become a feature [Vector] column. Such that I can follow the rest of the steps in https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/ml-classification-regression.html#tree-ensembles.

I have cast the columns too like suggested by zero323

```
val types = Map("strCol1" -> "string", "strCol2" -> "string")
        .withDefault(_ => "bigint")
df = df.select(df.columns.map(c => df.col(c).cast(types(c)).alias(c)): _*)
df = df.drop("f0")
df = df.drop("strCol1")
df = df.drop("strCol2")
```

But the assert and VectorAssembler still fails. 
featureColumns = Array("f2","f3",....."f11")
This is whole sequence I want to do after I have my df

```
    var transformeddf = new VectorAssembler()
    .setInputCols(featureColumns)
    .setOutputCol("features")
    .transform(df)

    transformeddf.show(2)

    transformeddf = new StringIndexer()
    .setInputCol("f1")
    .setOutputCol("indexedF1")
    .fit(transformeddf)
    .transform(transformeddf)

    transformeddf.show(2)

    transformeddf = new VectorIndexer()
    .setInputCol("features")
    .setOutputCol("indexedFeatures")
    .setMaxCategories(5)
    .fit(transformeddf)
    .transform(transformeddf)
```

The exception trace from ScalaIDE - just when it hits the VectorAssembler is as below

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.String cannot be cast to java.lang.Long
    at scala.runtime.BoxesRunTime.unboxToLong(BoxesRunTime.java:110)
    at scala.math.Numeric$LongIsIntegral$.toDouble(Numeric.scala:117)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.Cast$$anonfun$castToDouble$5.apply(Cast.scala:364)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.Cast$$anonfun$castToDouble$5.apply(Cast.scala:364)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.Cast.eval(Cast.scala:436)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.Alias.eval(namedExpressions.scala:118)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.CreateStruct$$anonfun$eval$2.apply(complexTypes.scala:75)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.CreateStruct$$anonfun$eval$2.apply(complexTypes.scala:75)
    at scala.collection.TraversableLike$$anonfun$map$1.apply(TraversableLike.scala:244)
    at scala.collection.TraversableLike$$anonfun$map$1.apply(TraversableLike.scala:244)
    at scala.collection.mutable.ResizableArray$class.foreach(ResizableArray.scala:59)
    at scala.collection.mutable.ArrayBuffer.foreach(ArrayBuffer.scala:47)
    at scala.collection.TraversableLike$class.map(TraversableLike.scala:244)
    at scala.collection.AbstractTraversable.map(Traversable.scala:105)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.CreateStruct.eval(complexTypes.scala:75)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.CreateStruct.eval(complexTypes.scala:56)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.ScalaUdf$$anonfun$2.apply(ScalaUdf.scala:72)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.ScalaUdf$$anonfun$2.apply(ScalaUdf.scala:70)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.ScalaUdf.eval(ScalaUdf.scala:960)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.Alias.eval(namedExpressions.scala:118)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.InterpretedMutableProjection.apply(Projection.scala:68)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.InterpretedMutableProjection.apply(Projection.scala:52)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$11.next(Iterator.scala:328)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$11.next(Iterator.scala:328)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$10.next(Iterator.scala:312)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$class.foreach(Iterator.scala:727)
    at scala.collection.AbstractIterator.foreach(Iterator.scala:1157)
    at scala.collection.generic.Growable$class.$plus$plus$eq(Growable.scala:48)
    at scala.collection.mutable.ArrayBuffer.$plus$plus$eq(ArrayBuffer.scala:103)
    at scala.collection.mutable.ArrayBuffer.$plus$plus$eq(ArrayBuffer.scala:47)
    at scala.collection.TraversableOnce$class.to(TraversableOnce.scala:273)
    at scala.collection.AbstractIterator.to(Iterator.scala:1157)
    at scala.collection.TraversableOnce$class.toBuffer(TraversableOnce.scala:265)
    at scala.collection.AbstractIterator.toBuffer(Iterator.scala:1157)
    at scala.collection.TraversableOnce$class.toArray(TraversableOnce.scala:252)
    at scala.collection.AbstractIterator.toArray(Iterator.scala:1157)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan$$anonfun$3.apply(SparkPlan.scala:143)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan$$anonfun$3.apply(SparkPlan.scala:143)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext$$anonfun$runJob$5.apply(SparkContext.scala:1767)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext$$anonfun$runJob$5.apply(SparkContext.scala:1767)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ResultTask.runTask(ResultTask.scala:63)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:70)
    at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:213)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You get `ClassCastException` because this is exactly what should happen. Schema argument is not used for automatic casting (some `DataSources` may use schema this way, but not methods like `createDataFrame`). It only declares what are the types of the values which are stored in the rows. It is you responsibility to pass data which matches the schema, not the other way around.

While `DataFrame` shows schema you've declared it is validated only on runtime, hence the runtime exception.If you want to transform data to specific you have `cast` data explicitly.

1. First read all columns as `StringType`:

   ```
   val rows = sc.textFile(staticfeatures_filepath)
     .map(line => Row.fromSeq(line.split(",")))

   val schema = StructType(
     schemaString.split(" ").map(
       columnName => StructField(columnName, StringType, false)
     )
   )

   val df = sqlContext.createDataFrame(rows, schema)
   ```
2. Next cast selected columns to desired type:

   ```
   import org.apache.spark.sql.types.{LongType, StringType}

   val types = Map("strcol1" -> StringType, "strcol2" -> StringType)
     .withDefault(_ => LongType)

   val casted = df.select(df.columns.map(c => col(c).cast(types(c)).alias(c)): _*)
   ```
3. Use assembler:

   ```
   val transformeddf = new VectorAssembler()
     .setInputCols(featureColumns)
     .setOutputCol("features")
     .transform(casted)
   ```

You can simply steps 1 and 2 using [`spark-csv`](https://github.com/databricks/spark-csv):

```
// As originally 
val schema = StructType(
  schemaString.split(" ").map(fieldName => getSFColumnDType(fieldName)))


val df = sqlContext
  .read.schema(schema)
  .format("com.databricks.spark.csv")
  .option("header", "false")
  .load(staticfeatures_filepath)
```

See also [Correctly reading the types from file in PySpark](https://stackoverflow.com/q/35920747/1560062)

Comment: Hmm. The assert does not work too. Say I have a simple file like this 1,A,20,P,-99,1,0,0,8,1,1,1,1,131153 \n
1,B,23,P,-99,0,1,0,7,1,1,0,1,65543 \n 
1,C,24,P,-99,0,1,0,9,1,1,1,1,262149 \n 
1,D,7,P,-99,0,0,0,8,1,1,1,1,458759 \n. (4 lines given as e.g) All I am trying to do is get the 3rd column as label and 5th to 11th column as features in a label/features kind of dataframe so that I can follow the steps mentioned in https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/ml-classification-regression.html#tree-ensembles and it seems so difficult!!! . Is there any way out ? Tested the above example - same error.

Comment: zero323  I added information in the question. The error is still the same even after using the Steps 1 and 2 you mentioned. Hope to hear from you soon. Will check back after some time.

Comment: I just tested this live on 1.4.0 and your data and works just fine. Please double check your code / settings.

Comment: Thanks a ton will check tom morning and update. Regds

Comment: Answer accepted. Thanks a lot. I have a doubt on the cast requirement though. I work on several gigabytes of data (RDD) with several hundred columns. I hope casting will not create additional overhead. Will soon find out and update..